# requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects while using Tagme in Python

Tags: python

My python code contains a method as follows:

```
import tagme

def concept_extraction ():
tagme.GCUBE_TOKEN = "702e87ce-3750-4069-900d-92d12a17cda4-843334162"
string = "Sachin is running in the Kolkata stadium."
print string
lunch_annotations = tagme.annotate(string)
#Print annotations with a score higher than 0.1
for ann in lunch_annotations.get_annotations(0.1):
    print ann
return;
```

Where for a given string, I want to determine the entities present in the string. But I am getting an error as follows:

```
File "/home/krishnendu/Python_workspace/QG/concept_extraction.py", line 8, in concept_extraction
lunch_annotations = tagme.annotate(string)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tagme/__init__.py", line 201, in annotate
json_response = _issue_request(api, payload, gcube_token)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tagme/__init__.py", line 271, in _issue_request
res = requests.post(api, data=payload)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-1.2.3-py2.7.egg/requests/api.py", line 88, in post
return request('post', url, data=data, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-1.2.3-py2.7.egg/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-1.2.3-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 335, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-1.2.3-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 454, in send
history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-1.2.3-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 87, in resolve_redirects
raise TooManyRedirects('Exceeded %s redirects.' % self.max_redirects)
requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects.
```

Question: The python version is 2.7 and tagme version is 0.1.3. How to handle this issue?

Comment: before trying to execute the python code. Set the environment variable `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` to the proxy value. `export https_proxy=http://x.y.z.a` and then run your script and see if it works

Comment: The previous error changed to a new one now, saying: Too many redirects.

Comment: You should manually validate your proxy and see if it works or not. export the variable and then do `curl ipinfo.io`

Comment: @Tarun: I edited my question which shows the current error and details.

Comment: It is tough to say this way what is wrong. If your proxy is a problem which is not handling the https connections well or it the tagme site which has a problem. Check on your proxy and see if it allows access to https urls or not

Comment: After exporting variables, I tried curl ipinfo.io and it worked fine. The error is coming still.